# Finding $\lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{1}{4} \pi } \frac{\tan x-\cot x}{x-\frac{1}{4} \pi }$.

Tags: limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

How do I get the value of

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow  \frac{1}{4} \pi  }  \frac{\tan x-\cot x}{x-\frac{1}{4} \pi }?$$

I need the steps without using L'hospital.

Comment: Have you tried L´Hôpital?

Comment: No. I can't use L'Hospital. I need to know the steps without L'Hospital.

Comment: Ah. Well, under those circumstances @idm's answer is a good alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firs note that $ \displaystyle \tan x - \cot x = - 2 \frac{\cos 2x}{\sin 2x}$. Then consider a change of variable $\displaystyle u=x-\frac{\pi}{4}$ to obtain

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow  \frac{1}{4} \pi  }  \frac{\tan x-\cot x}{x-\frac{1}{4} \pi }= \lim_{u \rightarrow  0  } [\frac{\sin 2u}{u}\times \frac{2}{\cos2u}]=\lim_{u \rightarrow  0  } [\frac{\sin 2u}{u}] \times \lim_{u \rightarrow  0  } [ \frac{2}{\cos2u}].$$ 
Now note that $ \displaystyle \lim_{u \rightarrow  0  } \frac{\sin 2u}{u} = 2  \lim_{u \rightarrow  0  } \frac{\sin 2u}{2 u} = 2 \lim_{t \rightarrow  0  } \frac{\sin t}{t} =2$, which has received some good bit of attention [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1).

The limit will hence be $\displaystyle 2 \times 2 =4$.

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me very well. I got the same result, but in the process I did some different way. I got $-2 \times -2=4$.

Comment: You are most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

$$...=\underbrace{\frac{1}{\tan x}}_{\to 1}\underbrace{\frac{\tan^2x-1}{(x-\frac{\pi}{4})}}_{ \to \frac{d}{dx}\tan^2(x)\big|_{x=\pi/4}}$$

Answer (score 1):

idm's answer is good, but L´Hôpital's rule is often more directly an instance of a limit actually being the limit of a difference quotient defining a derivative, or, in this case, a pair of difference quotients defining a pair of derivatives:

$$\frac{\tan x-\cot x}{x-\frac{1}{4} \pi } = \frac{\tan x - 1}{x-\frac{1}{4} \pi } - \frac{\cot x -1}{x-\frac{1}{4} \pi }.$$

then we have

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow  \frac{1}{4} \pi  }  \frac{\tan x-\cot x}{x-\frac{1}{4} \pi } = \lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{1}{4} \pi} \frac{\tan x - 1}{x-\frac{1}{4} \pi } - \frac{\cot x -1}{x-\frac{1}{4} \pi }$$
$$=\tan'\left(\frac{1}{4}\pi\right) - \cot'\left(\frac{1}{4}\pi\right)$$

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't get it. After this, what should I do next?

Comment: @NouvelRaka See my edit.

Comment: Yeah, I got it now. Thank you @Dustan... :)

Comment: @NouvelRaka no problem!